# How to add div and have it behave like a dev console?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to dynamically create a div on a page using JS and have it behave like a dev console behaves in Chrome and Firefox. By this, I mean that when the div is visible, it does not negatively impact the display of other DOM elements. It would simply either "push up" or "push down" elements on the page.

Is this possible without having to redesign the application's DOM elements to account for the "div console?"

I've tried generating the div as the first element on the page, **but that still would not account for DOM elements that are position absolute or fixed**:

```
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'wc-test-window';
  div.style.width = "100%";
  div.style.height = "200px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
  div.style.position = 'relative';
  div.style.top = 0;
  div.style.right = 0;
  div.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
```

Comment: Everything is possible! `:)`

Comment: @Ele Is it probable?

Comment: Can't believe I got negative votes on this. I want to create a div that would behave like a web console on ANY web application. That means that the target web application should NOT have to modify their DOM just to accommodate for the div web console. Of course this can be done if the target application were to be modified so that the div console would fit and behave as desired, but that's not what I'm asking. I should be able to downvote your non-constructive comments.

Comment: @Learnonhardway probably not :-P

Answer (score 1):

I'm disappointed in this community for all of the unconstructive comments and downvotes for a perfectly legitimate question. Anyway, I solved it using framesets and frames for anyone looking for a viable answer to this problem.

```
  function showDevConsole() {

    var fs = document.createElement('frameset'),
      f1 = document.createElement('frame'),
      f2 = document.createElement('frame');
    fs.rows = "200,*";
    fs.framespacing = "0";

    // top frame - show the dev console
    f1.name = "topframe";
    f1.src = "dev-console.html";
    f1.marginwidth = "0";
    f1.marginheight = "0";
    f1.noresize = "noresize";
    f1.scrolling = "no";

    // bottom frame - show current page
    f2.name = "bottomframe";
    f2.src = window.location;
    f2.marginwidth = "0";
    f2.marginheight = "0";
    f2.scrolling = "auto";
    f2.frameborder = "0";

    // append the frames to the frameset
    fs.appendChild(f1);
    fs.appendChild(f2);

    // replace the entire body with the framset containing both frames
    $("body").replaceWith(fs);

    return false;

  }
```

I put the current page on the bottom frame and the "console" at the top. Any DOM manipulations that the top frame can do on the bottom frame will be done via JS using the name or id of the frame.

Comment: Someone with that reputation number should be familiar with the rules of this site.

Comment: You mean asking a valid question, posting code examples of what I've attempted thus far, explaining what I want to accomplish, explaining barriers that I'm having difficulty overcoming before asking for help? No wonder so many people find this site to be toxic.